# ReactJS - Data does not load in dropdown list from axios call

Tags: reactjs

I have a React Component like below:

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => {
        // handle success
        let thedata = response.data;
        this.setState({ thedata });
        console.log(thedata);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select>
        {this.state.users.map((user) => (
          <option value={user.id}>{user.name}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  }
}
```

The data shows up on console just fine. But my dropdown stills shows empty. No error whatsoever. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `state` as `{thedata:thedata}` instead of `{users:thedata}`. Change it like so :-

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => {
        // handle success
        let thedata = response.data;
        this.setState({users:thedata });
        console.log(thedata);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```